# how to group by in SQL with latest date column

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone help me in a query. I want to select some rows which are grouped by thread_id column. I want to select only those rows which have latest date.. let me provide an example

```
thread_id | message_id | msg_date
tid_1     | mid_1      | 2018-01-10
tid_1     | mid_2      | 2018-01-14
tid_1     | mid_3      | 2018-01-13
tid_2     | mid_1      | 2018-01-11
tid_2     | mid_2      | 2018-01-12
```

I want a query which select all records from table but group them by `thread_id` and row with the latest date should be chosen. Expected output:

```
thread_id | message_id | msg_date
tid_1     | mid_2      | 2018-01-14
tid_2     | mid_2      | 2018-01-12
```

I also have a `msg_date_timestamp` column in my table. would be better if we order messages on the basis of `msg_date_timestamp` . what I have tried so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE user_id='".$email."' AND mailbox_label='INBOX' GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY msg_date_ts DESC
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE user_id='$email' AND mailbox_label='INBOX' AND msg_date_ts in (SELECT MAX(msg_date_ts) from emails GROUP BY thread_id) ORDER BY msg_date_ts DESC
```

Nothing worked as I expected. Also I want to get the count of messages in a thread. for example in thread tid_1, it should return `3` and for tid_2, it should return `2` . I want thread count in same query.. (not a separate query for count)
Please help me. really stucked.
Thanks!

Comment: What results are you getting from the queries you are running?